# Getting the successful deployments between dates or onbefore

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-delivery, azure-deployment

I am using the below API to get the successful deployment of a particular pipeline. I am not able to get the deployments happened between particular dates or before particular date.

I tried like below but not getting desired outputs any modification to the below API

Documentation can be found here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#releasequeryorder)

https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/ABC/DEF/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId=111&sourceBranch=master&createdOn=2022-10-06

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to get the deployments between particular dates or before particular date.

You need to use the parameter: `minStartedTime` and `maxStartedTime` to replace the `CreatedOn` to set the date .

For example:

**Between particular dates**

Rest API: use `minStartedTime` and `maxStartedTime`

```
Get https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId=xx&minStartedTime=2022-02-01&maxStartedTime=2022-02-17&api-version=6.0
```

**Before particular date** use  `maxStartedTime`

```
Get https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId=xx&maxStartedTime=2022-02-17&api-version=6.0
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Deployments - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)